# Python check_output (subprocess module) does not match documentation

Tags: python, subprocess, stdout

I am using Python 2.7.4 on Windows and am experiencing differences in the check_output() function from the subprocess module than what the python documentation shows.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html (see the second example box under the check_output documentation.

I am entering (In the python console shell):

```
>>>from subprocess import *
>>>check_output("ls non_existent_file; exit 0",
...    stderr=STDOUT,
...    shell=True)
```

According to the documentation, I should receive back:

```
'ls: non_existent_file: No such file or directory\n'
```

But instead, I receive:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<stdin>", line 3, in <module>
    File "C:\python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 573, in check_output
        raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd, output=output)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'ls non_existent_file; exit 0' returned non-zero exit status 1
```

I would appreciate any help in resolving this.

Comment: The command "ls" doesn't exist on windows (usually). So that's why. Also, your error-output indicates you miss a space between exit and 0. Not sure if exit exists, again.

Comment: deets, check_output("ls") works fine for me.  The Exit0 in the error was my typo, changed it to Exit 0 now.

Comment: Also, check_output("ls real_file") works fine too.

Comment: The example might not work in Windows. You can't expect the same behaviour from shell commands on different operating systems.

Try opening a command line and enter `ls non_existent_file; exit 0`

In linux, this will execute two commands, first `ls` which will return exit status 1 (error), and then `exit 0` which will return status 0 (OK). Subprocess will only see the last exit status. Maybe `exit 0` isn't a valid Windows command?

Comment: You seem to be on a non-standard environ then I guess. You use msys bash or cygwin?